# Overriding events in Sap ui 5

Tags: uiview, sapui5

I created custom Controller which Extends

```
 sap.ui.commons.ValueHelpField
```

and I want to override valueHelpRequest event but I was unable to override the method. I was overriding event like method. Can anyone tell me how to override the event

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal way of using a ValueHelpField.

```
    // create a default ValueHelpField
var oVHF1 = new sap.ui.commons.ValueHelpField('VHF1',{
    value: "default",
    tooltip: "This is a tooltip",
    valueHelpRequest: function(){alert('ValueHelpRequest fired');}
}).placeAt("sample1");
```

valueHelpRequest event has a user-defined function to be triggered. If the customization that you want could be in the event handler function, then you need not override event implementation.

Else if you would like to change the way the event is triggered, then please refer below:

For Every event 'xyz', a corresponding 'fireXyz' method is generated, which shall be called on native browser events like 'click' etc.,

Browser events shall be handled in the Control implementation in methods like 'onclick' for 'click', 'ontap' for 'tap'...

In ValueHelpField control, the fireValueHelpRequest method is called on browser events like 'click' and 'sapshow' i.e. from methods 'onclick' and 'onsapshow'.

If you would like custom behavior, then override methods 'onclick' and 'onsapshow', check the current implementation, and add customization as needed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

sap.ui.core.Control.extend("nabisoft.bookstore.controls.Book", {

```
        // the control API:
        metadata : {
            properties : {
                //some properties
            },

            aggregations : {
              //some aggregation
            },

            associations: {
                 //some association
            },

            events : {
                valueHelpRequest: function(e){
                                  alert("clicked");
                         }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sap.ui.commons.ValueHelpField.extend("HoverButton", {                                                
      metadata: {
          events: {
              "hover" : {} 
          }
      },  
      onmouseover : function(evt) {   
          this.fireHover();
      },   
      renderer: {} 

  });


 var myControl = new HoverButton("myBtn", {
              text: "Hover Me",
              hover: function(evt) {
                  alert("Button " + evt.getSource().getId() + " was hovered.");
              }
          });
          myControl.placeAt("content");


 var myControl = new HoverButton("myBtn", {
              text: "Hover Me",
              hover: function(evt) {
                  alert("Button " + evt.getSource().getId() + " was hovered.");
              }
          });
          myControl.placeAt("content");
```